# getProduct gives repeated product on cart page as additional info instead current product

Tags: module, magento2.3, product-attribute

I have developed a custom module to show additional product info on cart page.
My module is combo of:

1. https://webkul.com/blog/add-product-information-checkout-cart-in-magento2/ (https://github.com/webkul/magento2_cartPageAdditionalInfo)
   &
2. https://www.atwix.com/magento-2/how-to-add-the-details-for-cart-item-in-magento-2/

I want to fetch the current product attribute as additional info for every next product in cart. But I get the same product attribute/name which is first cart product.

Basically I have extended module 1 and added module 2 into it. So instead of returning static text *Additional information* from module 1 block method. I wanted to return custom attribute of current product using module 2.

**See following image:**

[image: Shopping cart product data]

**My block source code:**

```
    namespace Mcs\AccessoryMainData\Block;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterfaceFactory;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product;
use Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Additional\Info as AdditionalBlockInfo;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException;
/**
 * AdditionalProInfo.
 */
class AdditionalProInfo extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{

    /**
     * Product
     *
     * @var ProductInterface|null
     */
    protected $product = null;
    /**
     * Product Factory
     *
     * @var ProductInterfaceFactory
     */
    protected $productFactory;

    protected $abstractViewBlock;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context  $context
     * @param array                                             $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        ProductInterfaceFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\AbstractView $abstractViewBlock,
        \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct $abstractProduct,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->logger = $logger;
        $this->abstractViewBlock = $abstractViewBlock;
        $this->abstractProduct = $abstractProduct;
    }

    /**
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
    }

    /**
     * @return $this
     */
    protected function _prepareLayout()
    {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
    }

    /**
     * @return additional information data
     */
    public function getAdditionalData()
    {
        $product = $this->getProduct();
        return $product->getName();
    }

    /**
     * Get product from quote item
     *
     * @return ProductInterface
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        if ($this->product instanceof ProductInterface) {
            return $this->product;
        }
        try {
            $layout = $this->getLayout();
        } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
            $this->product = $this->productFactory->create();
            return $this->product;
        }
        /** @var AdditionalBlockInfo $block */
        $block = $layout->getBlock('additional.product.info');
        if ($block instanceof AdditionalBlockInfo) {
            $item = $block->getItem();
            $this->product = $item->getProduct();
        }
        return $this->product;
    }   
}
```

**Following is my layout xml file code:**

```
 <page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="additional.product.info">
            <block class="Mcs\AccessoryMainData\Block\AdditionalProInfo"
                   name="cart_item_addional_info_block" 
                   template="Mcs_AccessoryMainData::checkout/cart/item/additionalinfo.phtml" 
                   cacheable="false"
            />
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

**Following is my phtml file source code:**

```
$_item = $block->getItem();
$product = $_item->getProduct(); // Get cart product details
$additional_data = $block->getAdditionalData(); // Get cart product additionl details defined in block page
?>
<div>
    <span><?php echo $additional_data?></span>
</div>
```

Please help me on this.

Comment: Show your code that you tried

Comment: Thanks for your reply @SohelRana.
I have added now all my source code related to it. Please check it now.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with Mcs\AccessoryMainData\Block\AdditionalProInfo:getProduct().

Here is the latest code for it:

```
public function getProduct()
{
    $product = null;
    try {
        $layout = $this->getLayout();
    } catch (LocalizedException $e) {
        $product = $this->productFactory->create();
        return $product;
    }
    /** @var AdditionalBlockInfo $block */
    $block = $layout->getBlock('additional.product.info');
    if ($block instanceof AdditionalBlockInfo) {
        $item = $block->getItem();
        $product = $item->getProduct();
        $this->logger->log('Info', 'Item data : ', [$item, $this->product]);
    }
    return $product;
}
```

Plus I was missing catalog_attribute.xml inside etc/ folder.
This is the code for it:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
  <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Catalog:etc/catalog_attributes.xsd">
<group name="quote_item">
    <attribute name="name"/>
</group>
```